# Fast-API and MySQL Docker Integration

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, sqlalchemy, dockerfile, fastapi

**docker-copmose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  fast_api_project:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
    networks:
      - deploy_fast_api_project
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - deploy_fast_api_project
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-password}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE:-db_name}

networks:
  deploy_fast_api_project:
      driver: bridge
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

CMD ["sh","run.sh"]
```

**.env**

```
mysql_database_url=mysql+pymysql://username:password@host/db_name
```

**specifications:**
1)Fast-api.
2)mysql

In local i am able to connect and all operations are working.

When i try to build through docker i am getting this error, **sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")**

What is missing here, or what i need to add here.. Thanks for inputs.
( I am connecting to local mysql which is running on and connecting like this **mysql -u username -h host -p** ).

Comment: Your FastAPI project needs to connect to `mysql` as the host; `127.0.0.1` refers to the network _inside the fastapi container_.

Comment: have you tried those steps: [How to run FastAPI and connect to a MySQL database using a Docker compose file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74114540/how-to-run-fastapi-and-connect-to-a-mysql-database-using-a-docker-compose-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.env file**

`mysql_database_url=mysql+pymysql://username:password@mysql:host/db_name`

This will solve the problem.

**@mysql** is the service name of MySQL which i am using(defined) in **docker-compose.yml** file